# debug spyder using breakpoints in editor and code calling from console

Tags: spyder

My impression is that in Spyder breakpoints are triggered when calling execution with debugging. My normal workflow is to write some code and then type a line or two to test that code in the console. Doing so fails to trigger the breakpoint. Instead to debug I am constantly typing `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the editor where I want the breakpoint to be triggered. Is there a way of getting the console to respect breakpoints (ideally by default) so that I can just type a line or two to run my code and then get the editor breakpoints to be respected? I guess the alternative is to create a temporary file for placing my temporary code, although that is not ideal. Often I have the code in the library I am writing as an example in the comments, and I'm simply selecting that code snippet and asking the selection to be executed.

I'm using Spyder 4.2 on Windows for reference.